# Neo4j: Traversal is depreactaed in the new version 3.0.1

Tags: neo4j, traversal

I am updating to the latest version of neo4j 3.0.1. However, the Traversal `pathExpanderForAllTypes` method is deprecated and I got errors. I couldn't find the equivalent method which can be used with 3.0.1.

```
  import org.neo4j.kernel.Traversal;
  PathExpander<Object> expander = Traversal.pathExpanderForAllTypes(Reldir);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look to a [previous version Javadoc about neo4j](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel/2.2.0/org/neo4j/kernel/Traversal.java#Traversal.pathExpanderForAllTypes%28org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction%29), you will see that this method, along with most of the class has been deprecated.

But you can also see that there are some hints in the code in order to overcome this issue:

> Returns a org.neo4j.graphdb.PathExpander which expands relationships
>   of all types in the given direction.
>
> Deprecated: See
>   [org.neo4j.graphdb.PathExpanders.forDirection(org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel/2.2.0/org/neo4j/graphdb/PathExpanders.java#PathExpanders.forDirection%28org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction%29)
>   Returns: a path expander which expands all relationships in the given
>   direction.

```
360
361    @Deprecated
362    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
363    public static <STATE> PathExpander<STATE> More ...pathExpanderForAllTypes( Direction direction )
364    {
365        return StandardExpander.create( direction );
366    }
```

So I reccommend you to check the method: `org.neo4j.graphdb.PathExpanders.forDirection(Direction)` , or one of the others provided by the [`PathExpanders`](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PathExpanders.html) class.